# SQL - choose number from string, and replace it

Tags: mysql, sql

I hav the next query in SQL:
SELECT id FROM student WHERE DATE LIKE '%$inputdate'
the inputDate is in the next format: 2010.08.03
I also want to change the date of the date, by increasing the day in a week (+7).

I try this:

```
SELECT id
FROM student
WHERE DATE LIKE '%$inputdate'
     OR DATE Like '%CAST(RIGHT("2012-11-03", 2)AS INT) + 7;
```

But it gives me SQL syntax error. How can I write it correctly?

Comment: What SQL engine are you dealing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using `MySQL`, make use of `DATE()` function

```
SELECT id
FROM student
WHERE DATE(`DATE`) = DATE(inputdate) OR 
      DATE(`DATE`) = DATE(DATE_ADD(DATE(inputdate),INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

SOURCES

- [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)
- [DATE_ADD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: Thank you. it still not working, because it like the DATA_ADD. How I do that?

Comment: do you mean `DATE_ADD`? what is the data type of `DATE`  in your table? is it date ot stored as varchar?

Comment: I got as an input: 2012-11-03, and I want to find the Id's with there date 2010-11-10. But because I also have the hour, it's like the data column, and not equal.

Comment: that's why you have to use the function `DATE` so it will get rid of the time. Let me clarify some things, 1.) what is the format if `inputdate`? 2.) what is the data type of `DATE` column, is it `DATE` or `varchar`? I also updated the answer.